# AWS CodePipeline - for backend service and client (Angular)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have one question to you - I have an app - one backend service (based on Spring Boot) and one frontend /client (Angular 9). I'd like to create CI/CD with CodePipeline (CodeBuild, CodeDeploy) - all containerized with Docker. I have 2 Bitbucket repositories, for backend and frontend.

Can I have one ElasticBeanstalk with 1 CodePipeline that has 2 sources? Or maybe should I create 2 ELBs? What in case when I changed only backend code, my fronted will be unnecessarily build and deployed despite no changes?
I'd like to have backend and fronted on 1 EC2 instance only.

Thanks:)